# Can't answer my own question

Tags: support, questions, answers

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822656/wpf-cannot-delete-image-from-code-ioexception) about 8 days ago, and since then I figured out the answer. No other answer is correct, because I made the mistake of leaving out a tiny detail.

My problem is that the answer textbox on the bottom is not there...

Comment: Your question is **on hold** as a duplicate - nobody can add new answers unless it's reopened. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions. If you believe the question *isn't* a duplicate, and the answers on the proposed dupe don't solve your problem, **edit it** to clarify (for example, what is the *"tiny detail"* you left out?)

Comment: well, the code itself is good, and should be working, so it could not have an answer, since that is not the problem. the problem was the thing i left out. I cant imagine why someone would mark it duplicate just because on first sight it seemed so.

Comment: You'd have to ask them, but note that they have a gold badge in that topic, suggesting that they know what they're talking about. Again, if you think it should be reopened, **edit it** - how is anyone supposed to help if there's information you already know wasn't included?!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is, that the question was on hold as a duplicate.